# yii Making stylish link button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

Here is nice collection of icons caleld **Glyphicons**
http://getbootstrap.com/components/
They act like nice buttons, just without hyperlinks. Just mouseover actions.

What I want is to make buttons with hyperlinks and such style.
I have Bootstrap installed so I can use that css class.
Problem is that structure of button there is

```
<ul class='bs-glyphicon-list'><li><span>...</span><span>...</span></li></ul>
```

and if I use yii CHtml button then I have to write something like:

```
CHtml::link(BsHtml::icon(BsHtml::GLYPHICON_PLUS).'some text', 
array('controller/action'), $htmlOptions=array ('class'=>'bs-glyphicon-list'));
```

Problem is that that additional html options will be passed to  tag itself.
And I have to make ul+li+span junction. How can I achive this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a little unclear on what the problem here is. But this should work if you use Chtml::htmlbutton.

```
<?php echo CHtml::htmlButton('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> ' . Yii::t('search', 'Search'), array('class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'id'=>'submit-search', 'type'=>'submit')); ?>
```

but htmlButton allows you to use the glyiphicons in plain text, whilst still passing other css and options to it.

Will render a bootstrap button with chosen glyphicon in the text

Comment: Jonny thanks, that's nearly just what I wanted. But what if '"search" text should be placed below icon? and both icons and text must be horizontally aligned to center of the button?

Comment: You could always house the search text in a `<span>` tag and then add a css class to the span tag and if necessary the `<i>` tag if necessary, from there add the rules to the css to achieve this. Or I just tried this: `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i><br /> ' . Yii::t('search', 'Search')` (adding a <br> tag. Should also align I think